# Receiving Empty Records even after successful code execution in SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest

This is my restMethod which I am calling from UI. The rest method fetches data from postgres database. If I try to debug the code, I could see that the List is having all required output data from database response, but the when the pointer passes the List and comes in return section it seems the data is getting nulled out.

```
 @ApiOperation(value = "All EhcStats fetched successfully", response = ResponseEntity.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "All EhcStats  fetched successfully")})
    @RequestMapping(value="/getAllEhcStats", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<EhcStatus>> getAllEhcStats() {

            List<EhcStatus> EhcStatsRecord = this.transactionService.getAllStats();
            if(null != EhcStatsRecord) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(EhcStatsRecord, HttpStatus.OK);
            }
            else {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
            }

    }
```

Below is what I am getting in swagger response.

```
[{}]
```

Comment: Your JSON is not empty, it is a list with one element that has no properties! On the other hand your controller method looks ok, but the observed behaviour sounds very very strange. (To be honest, I don't really believe it is.) - I think you should look for a problem with the JSON serialisation. Maybe there is a issue that make  your `EhcStatsRecord` serialize into an empty json object (one without properties).

Comment: Thanks Ralph, but u'll have to believe me.  I too find it very strange, but getting helpless to find the answer.

Comment: I belive that the behavior in the Debugger looks exactly like you described. But (belive me) it will need a lot of effort to develop such a behaviour.  - So it is more likely that the problem is something else.

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of the `TransactionService` and the `EhcStatus` class.